# sort different data obejcts in same row with react-table

Tags: react-table

I'm really not sure how to describe what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to create a react-table component where my data is organized in a certain way.

Let's say I have a list of objects like this:

```
{ id: '887SYEP',
    client: 'CS',
    side: 'S',
    price: 85.8125,
    qty: 9866000,
    id: '8a59875bdaca5f886c5e7bdc42bb753b78cbe59d' }
```

Please see the image attached. If "side" prop is "B" then then the price and related data is bid data and if its "S" then its offer data.  each object is a stock quote.  however i want to order it in such a way that the table looks like this where the highest bids and offers are at the top:

[image of ideal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7tFW.png)

This data is in one row even though its two separate quote objects. the corresponding "client" and "price" are to the left if its "side" property is type "S" and to the right if its "B" (buy/sell side).  is there a way to use one table to achieve this or do i need two?  the Bid and Offer prices are only related in so much as its the same stock and a way for the user to see the top prices for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should filter Buyers and Sellers

```
let buyers = orders.filter(obj => obj.side === "B")
let sellers = orders.filter(obj => obj.side === "S")
```

then sort both by price

```
buyers.sort((a,b) => a.price < b.price)
sellers.sort((a,b) => a.price > b.price)
```

for simplicity let assume both arrays are of the same length. to combine them do:

```
let orders = []
for (let index in buyers) {
    let {client: BClient, qty: BQty, price: Bid} = buyers[index]
    let {client: SClient, qty: SQty, price: Offer} = sellers[index] 
    orders.push({
        BClient,
        BQty,
        Bid,
        Offer,
        SQty,
        SClient
    })
}
```

then display `orders`